# Tab Item not responding

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am creating a small dashboard but my sidebarMenu items are not reacting as required. One of the menu items takes the values of the other two and not what has been assigned to it. What am I missing, is it some bracket issue? My code is as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Transport Data"), dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("About", tabName = "About", icon = icon("file-lines")),
    menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Analysis", icon = icon("share-alt")),
    menuItem("Raw Data", tabName = "Raw Data", icon = icon("table"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "About",
        title = h1("Total Vehicle Count"),
        ##############################################################
        tags$b("Total Vehicle Count"),
        br(),
        ##############################################################

        "  Visualization and Analysis Tool for Traffic Count Data"
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Analysis",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 3,
            box(
              title = "Metadata",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              collapsible = TRUE,
              width = NULL,
              "TEXT"
            )
          ),
          column(
            width = 9,
            tabBox(
              width = "100%",
              tabsetPanel(
                id = "TextData",
                tabPanel(
                  "PLOT1",
                  plotOutput("Plot1")
                ),
                tabPanel(
                  "PLOT2",
                  plotOutput("Plot2")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Raw Data",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 3,
            box(
              title = "data1",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              collapsible = TRUE,
              width = NULL,
              "HI"
            )
          ),
          column(width = 9, tabBox(
            width = "100%",
            tabsetPanel(
              id = "TextData",
              tabPanel("TABLE1", tableOutput(outputId = "table1")),
              tabPanel("TABLE2", tableOutput(outputId = "table2"))
            )
          ))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point()
  })
  output$Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point()
  })

  output$table1 <- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$table2 <- renderTable(mtcars)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have not found a reference on that: But try without spaces in `tabName=`, i.e. use e.g. `tabName="RawData"`.